# How do I get the coordinates of the end using distance and vector in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arcore

I did something to get the depth distance using XRCpuImage in AROcciusionManager.
But I want to get the coordinates of the end using this distance.
The starting point is (0, 0, 0), and I want to get the coordinates in the direction away from it by this distance.
How do I get the coordinates of the end using distance and vector in unity?
Also, I tried to convert the rotation information of Unity into an angle and get it in the spherical coordinate system, but I don't know how.

Comment: currestPosition + (Direction * Distance) = destinationPosition

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `Vector3` of the `direction`, To find a point along that vector `distance` away from the `origin`, you can use:

```cs
Vector3 PointAlongDirection(Vector3 origin, Vector3 direction,
 float distance) {
  return origin + direction.normalized * distance;
}
```

A good reference is [Understanding Vector Arithmetic](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/Manual/UnderstandingVectorArithmetic.html).

Comment: What should I do with the direction value in AR?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? The direction is the vector that defines the line your point lies on. By normalizing it, you make it have a length (distance) of 1 so you can multiply it by your distance to get the end point?

Comment: OR, are you saying, you have the distance to a point but not the direction vector to that point?